# Running shell scripts on a remote machine from an ASP.Net/Winforms application

Tags: asp.net, shell

I have some shell scripts on a Windows 2003 server. These scripts process some flat files and upload data to Oracle using sqlldr. Currently I'm using telnet to go into the box and run each of these scripts manually. Is there a way that these scripts can be run from a ASP.Net/Winforms application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing similar things with Windows Communication Foundation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx